# Retrieve Variables/Accesing Variables in different Workspaces

Tags: matlab

I imported some data and them cleaned it up, there is a lot of data so this is quite time consuming.

I then wrote a scipt that uses these variables.

However when I went to run the script, it says that these varibles are not know. In the workspace editor is only shows variables declared in the script.

Q1.) Is there a way to get the original variables back?

Secondly as the clean up operation takes quite some time I don't want to have to import that data and clean in every time I run the M-file.

Q2.) So once I have the cleaned data how do I make these variables available to an M file (do I have to declare them as global or something like that?)

To be clear I tried to just debug the script rather than running it from the command window, I just wnat to get the base variables back now if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ahem there was a errant clear used in the script that's why all the variables were disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

A misplaced Clear or Clear all may be the problem. Similar thing happened to me once.